# Swagger error Springboot Could not resolve view with name 'forward:/swagger-ui/index.html'

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, swagger-ui

Springboot 2.5.13, swagger2:
implementation "io.springfox:springfox-boot-starter:3.0.0"
implementation "io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:3.0.0"

Runtime error:
Could not resolve view with name 'forward:/swagger-ui/index.html'

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The solution: create a bean like this:

```
  @Bean
  public InternalResourceViewResolver defaultViewResolver() {
    return new InternalResourceViewResolver();
  }
```

source: https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi/issues/236